# Parameterizing A Surface Integral Problem

Tags: surface-integrals, parametrization

"Evaluate the surface integral for the portion of a cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ between the planes $z=1$ and $z=4$."

**My Work**

The major issue that I'm having is with the parameterization, as this cylinder involves 3 relevant parameters $r$,$z$, and $\theta$. The integral is:

$\int\int|r_u\times r_v|dudv$

I originally thought that I might be able to just say $r=1$ therefore $x=rcos\theta=cos\theta,y=rsin\theta=sin\theta,z=z$ and end with **r**$= ⟨cos\theta,sin\theta,z ⟩$. However, if I do this, I get:

**r**$_z= ⟨ 0,0,1⟩$

**r**$_\theta =  ⟨ -sin\theta,cos\theta,0⟩$

Which, when crossed, results in:

$ ⟨ cos\theta,0,0⟩$

Therefore resulting in the integral

$\int_1^4\int_0^{2\pi} cos\theta d\theta dz$

Which is $0$. Clearly, this is wrong, and probably a result of my setup, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Would anyone be able to point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ does equal 1.

I amd going to use $S$ for the surface instead of $\mathbf r$

$S(z,\theta) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0) + (0,0,z)\\
\frac {dS}{dz} \times \frac {dS}{d\theta}  = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0)\ dz\ d\theta$

but what we really need is:

$\|\frac {dS}{dz} \times \frac {dS}{d\theta}\|  = 1 \ dz\ d\theta$